# int vs Float in regression modeling

Tags: regression, machine-learning, boosting

This is general question to understand a concept.

I have a dataframe with all columns having float values(precision varies from 2 to 8 digits).

I use GBM to train my model. When i train my model with all float values - r2 score -0.78

Same when all columns are converted to integer values - r2 score -0.72

Why does r2 score drop when float is converted to integer ?

Is it something very specific to my data or in general is it expected to drop ?

Comment: As soon as you mention rounding integers I stop and ask: Why do that?

Comment: our data represents operations per second and that is given per hour, so it is like 100 operations in hour = 100/60*60 ops (float). But the problem is input that will be given to model in 'real world' will always be integers, eg- 200ops. Hence I was trying to assess the impact with float & ints.

Comment: I don't follow. But if real data will be integers, how fake data with fractional parts behave differently when rounded to integers isn't necessarily going to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your results make perfect sense.  I would even advance you are lucky.  Yes, you are lucky that your drop in R Square in your model is not much more pronounced.  This phenomenon is I think pretty much related to what is known as the "Butterfly Effect."  This means that a very tiny difference in inputs can make at times a drastic difference in output and model fit.

When your inputs had a lot of decimals, they were very precise and captured accurately the necessary data for your regression model to capture the relationship between your X variables and your Y variable as accurately as possible.  So, you got a higher R Square.

When you used integer numbers, you lost quite a bit of information.  You sort of lost some Signal and introduced some Noise in your data.  The rounding creates some incremental random errors in your data set, and your R Square dropped.  That's perfectly normal.  That is what you would expect all the time.

Inherently, there is nothing wrong with your model and the mentioned divergence in R Square.  If anything, it suggests that your results are reasonably robust because even when using rounded numbers, the R Square holds up pretty well.

It would be interesting to see if the rounding affected the statistical significance of some of your X variables.  And, if it has... this may warrant additional testing on those X variables.  You could use rolling regressions to see how stable your X variables regression coefficients are.

Comment: This is a run-away argument. First, a story for why $R^2$ went down is not much more convincing than a visceral reaction that you are not surprised at a change in results (me neither). But severe rounding of bivariate data to two distinct points would yield an $R^2$ of 1, so rounding could work either way, to reduce noise rather than to add it. Second, what case is there for "additional testing"? As far as I can understand the question, the OP mangled their data, and my first reaction is to ask why, rather than to suggest exploration of that mangling or any other.

Comment: The Butterfly Effect is a pretty well established phenomenon.  You are welcome to research it yourself.  The additional testing can be explorative and informative and may reveal some instability in some relationships.  Your argument about the rounding having a potential effect in the opposite direction (higher R Square) is interesting.  And, I can see how that could occur.  I just wonder if that effect diminishes the larger the sample is (once you get out of the small sample error zone that can swing things randomly).

Comment: Wow!, thanks for such nice inferences. That helps me to understand better.